# how do you load jqgrid with json object from webservice?

Tags: jquery, web-services, jqgrid

I have a webservice and jqgrid, I want to load jqgrid with database's table

1. I have written the method `getdata()`
2. If create class is  necessary, please show me what to write
3. If my code is amiss, please show me where it is amiss

   [WebMethod]

   ```
   public  string  getdata()
   {

       SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from customer", con);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       da.Fill(ds);

       string data=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
       return  data;
   }
   ```

my script code is :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#jqgriddemo").jqGrid({

                url: "http://localhost:62442/WebServices/MyWebService.asmx" + "/" + "getdata",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 },
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'id',

                loadonce: true,
                rowlist: [10, 20, 30],
                mtype: 'POST',
                pager: '#pager',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                caption: 'First Jqgrid',
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "d.rows",
                    page: "d.page",
                    total: "d.total",
                    records: "d.records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    userdata: "userdata"
                },
            });

        });
```

Please show me a better way, or provide me a link to solve this problem.